# How to restore commit that are not in any branch but in a tag on github

Tags: github

I have a repository where I made many commits in January. Fast forward to July, when I was tinkering with Git, I got to know about the `Releases` feature.

Since I had many major features to push, I decided to create a new release.

Now I need the January commits for showing to someone but there is no trace of them anywhere, neither in the Commits section nor in releases. It just shows `4 commits since this release`

The commit history shows as if I started commiting to the repo from July only

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/codersrank-org/repo_info_extractor/commits/master) is a public repo with releases. But it does not have the problem you described. 
Try adding /commits/master or /commits/main to the end of the link to your repo and see if that works.

Comment: Additionally, if your repository is public, including the link in your question might be the fastest way to get help.

Comment: @Kitswas Before the first relaese of 0.1.0 in the public repo, there is no more history. My problem is that I commited many times before creating the very first release

Comment: 'I commited many times before creating the very first release' - This should not be a problem unless you had force-pushed.

Comment: "Releases" are a Git*Hub* feature, not a Git feature. (Please use the correct tag in the future.)

Comment: @Kitswas My repo only had `main` branch from start. I found out that when I made the release, I also created a tag like `v1.1`. And in the `Switch branches/tags` option when I switched to that tag, all the commits were there. So, my **history was bascially branch-less**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow, my entire history was stored not in branch but in a tag that I created when creating that release.

That's why even going too much deeper didn't reveal anythin since the commits were HEADless.

[image]
[image]

I noted the tag's hash and did

```
git checkout tag-hash              // now no branch checked out
git checkout -b new-branch-name tag-hash      //  created new branch from that tag
```

And with this, my new branch has the whole commit history